# Python within python

Tags: python

I have two python scripts. First python script calls second. But seconds python script should use one variable from first script to give desired result. I know I can just writes those few codes in second script to first one simply. But I am curious how to do this on this way. 
Tnx.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second script can import the first one:

Script A:

```
def something():
    foo = 'bar'
    return foo
```

Script B:

```
import A

var = A.something()
```

**or:**

Script A:

```
def something():
    foo = 'bar'
```

Script B:

```
import A

var = A.something().foo
```

Comment: Thank you. What I tried was with subprocess.Popen, but had some problems.